# Make Buffering on Epub Page Using FolioReaderKit

Tags: swift

I have collection view. Users can download and display it, i'm using FolioReaderKit to view the epub files and using alamofire download to download epub files.

is that possible if i make buffering page? So the download hasn't completed but user can still view the page that already downloaded while the progress download still running and download the next page?

Answer (score 0):

Today FolioReaderKit do not support file stream, the actual architecture needs the full .epub (zip) file to unzip, parse and present the book.

Although, we have future plans for file stream, today it is not possible unless you clone and implement it.

If you download the files unzipped you also can make a custom `FREpubParser.swift` that reload and parse the files as you download it.